# QML Swipeview no animation

Tags: qt, qml, swipeview

Is it possible to remove the animation from swipeviews? The one where you see the transition from the previous and the next page. I have many pages and I have a menu that selects the active item like:

```
mainContent.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

where mainContent is the swipeview.

```
    // The content changes based on what is clicked on in the menu
    SwipeView{
        width: mainWindow.width - mainMenuId.width -anchors.leftMargin
        id:mainContent
        anchors.leftMargin:  20
        anchors.topMargin: 20
        clip:true
        Component.onCompleted: contentItem.interactive = false
        currentIndex: 0

        Item{PageMain{}}                 
        Item{PageTests{}}             
        Item{PageData{}}                                
        Item{PageSavedFiles{}}                          
        Item{PageProbe{}}                               

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can override the [contentItem](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/SwipeView.qml?id=ce7c431fb23157fa5125d1102a594de045818a72#n49) and [disable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlightMoveDuration-prop) ListView's animation, or, if you don't really need the swipe part of SwipeView, use e.g. [StackLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html#details) instead:

```
TabBar {
    id: bar
    width: parent.width
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Home")
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Discover")
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Activity")
    }
}

StackLayout {
    width: parent.width
    currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
    Item {
        id: homeTab
    }
    Item {
        id: discoverTab
    }
    Item {
        id: activityTab
    }
}
```

That code is using TabBar, but I think you get the idea. :)

Comment: Thanks I ended up using the StackLayout, I can set the currnet index with: currentIndex=newIndex instead of setCurrentIndex(newIndex). Works as I wanted now.